# How to convert BufferedWriter to a Byte Array in Python?

Tags: python, c, arrays, rest, bufferedwriter

I'm trying to convert a Buffered writer to a byte array so that I can send it as a HttpRequest Param to my Java API.

Here is how the bufferedwriter `imageFile` is implemented in my Python code which uses C libraries:

```
filename = "filename.raw"
buffer = (c_char*width*height)()
result = lib.getResult(buffer)

imageFile = open(filename, "wb")
imageFile.write(buffer)

r = request.put("url", data={'byte_array': IMAGEFILE_AS_BYTE_ARRAY})
```

What is the correct way to convert `imageFile` which is a bufferedWriter to a byte[] so that Java can take it as a byte[]?

Comment: `(c_char*width*height)()` how does this even work?

Comment: I believe it's instantiating a C Pointer of width x height?

Comment: Ah sorry about that, I didn't notice that `c_char` was from `ctypes`, makes sense.